# How do I edit a properties file without trashing the rest of it

Tags: java

**Example.properties**

```
user=somePerson
env=linux
file=mpg
```

**properties.java class**

```
propertiestTest.java
   {
     Properties props = new Properties();
     props.setProperty("user", "GodIsUser");
     final File propsFile = new File(someDir/Example.properties");

     props.store(new FileOutputStream(propsFile), "");
}
```

**reseult of Example.properties**

```
user=GodIsUser
```

and all other entries are deleted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to populate it from the file first using [`props.load`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29):

```
final File propsFile = new File("someDir/Example.properties");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile));
// make changes
props.save(new FileOutputStream(propsFile), "");
```

Comment: Thank you! Response time was awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `props.load(inStream)` to load the existing props first.

 first use [Properties.load()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29), and only after it: modify the properties by using `Properties.setProperty()`

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the properties file into a Properties object.
2. Add the new properties.
3. Store the newly updated Properties object.

Step 1 above is the key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `put`:

```
//Load the props
final File propsFile = new File(someDir/Example.properties");

Properties props = load(new FileOutputStream(propsFile));
props.put("user", "GodIsUser");

props.store(new FileOutputStream(propsFile), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        FileInputStream fileName=new FileInputStream(fname);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(fileName);
        props.setProperty(Id, value);
        fileName.close();
        FileOutputStream outFileName=new FileOutputStream(fname);
        props.store(outFileName, "");
        outFileName.close();
        } catch (IOException io) {

            io.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If there is a need close the file , do it as mentioned above.